# Use IF in a WHERE clause in MySQL to order conditions and update a column (of a schedule of shows)

Tags: mysql, json, if-statement, case

I am building a radio schedule where I want to show the current show or the upcoming show or at last the next day's show. If it returns the next day's show I would like to add somthing to the title like `CONCAT_WS(" ", "Don't miss tomorrow:", title)`. The schedule is in JSON format so I am using `JSON_EXTRACT` and `TIME_FORMAT` to be able to compare values of hours. Here is what currently works, except that it shows the upcoming show or the next day's. Where there are days like "tuesday" it is an example for today and wednesday for tomorrow. The `BETWEEN` condition and the next one select the current show `OR` the upcoming show for today. How can I check if none of these apply, and if so select the next day's and update the title?

```
 SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE visible = 1 AND 
  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(schedule, '$.tuesday.active')) = 1 
  AND 
  ( 
    (
        TIME_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i') BETWEEN 
      TIME_FORMAT(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(schedule, '$.tuesday.time[0]')), '%H:%i') AND 
        TIME_FORMAT(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(schedule, '$.tuesday.time[1]')), '%H:%i')
    ) 
    OR 
    (
        TIME_FORMAT(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(schedule, '$.tuesday.time[0]')), '%H:%i') > TIME_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i') AND 
      TIME_FORMAT(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(schedule, '$.tuesday.time[1]')), '%H:%i') < TIME_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i')
    )
    OR
    (
        id = (SELECT id FROM tableName WHERE visible = 1 AND JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(schedule, '$.wednesday.active')) = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
    )
  ) 
  LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Please keep adding info per [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

i removed the 2nd OR condition and added a UNION with the same condition, so by limiting it by one, it returns the first row from first select, else the next day's